# How to reference a function from controller that is my libs folder?

Tags: angularjs

I found this ionic overlay menu on github (https://github.com/brybott/ionic-ion-drawer).

I want to make my own directive attribute called `close-drawer` so that upon clicking a link in my `<ion-list>` the drawer will close.

However, the controller for the drawer is in a file called `ionic.contrib.drawer.js` in my libs folder.  In the directive, I want to put controller as:

`controller: 'drawerCtrl'`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference it by name, so `controller: 'drawerCtrl'` is fine. Don't forget to include the library with a script tag in your HTML, and reference it in your main module.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ionic.contrib.drawer', ...])
.directive('MyDirective', function() {
    return {
        controller: 'drawerCtrl',
        // ...
    };
});

<script src="libs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="libs/ionic.contrib.drawer.js"></script>
<script src="js/close-drawer.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- etc... -->
```

Comment: hey sorry but I think in this case, I will have to use some kind of scope binding right?  It shows error: '$scope.toggleDrawer is not a function'.  Is this because it is looking in the $scope of the main controller and not the ion.contrib.drawer's drawerCtrl?